# How to add multiple row at same time from songle form?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vb6

I want to add my students name in table.
So what is the procedure of adding 10 or 20 names at a time to database using single windows form.
In visual studio 2013 visual basic windows form application
Thanks in advance

Comment: Pick a tag, VB6 and Visual-Studio-2013 are completely different. Also, please show the code for what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a datagrid in the form and add as many rows as you want.

add rows in your table using a loop reading from the datagrid